# Does HTML5 audio stream, or download and then play

Tags: html, audio

I intend to put together a web based player for myself. Is it possible to stream audio files using the html5  tag? or will they fully download and then play. Is any special server configuration required to play these files

Also what if the audio is not a file on the server but being dynamically generated on the server side with the raw bytes being written to the response stream

Comment: good question, I'm going to run into this problem soon as well, if it can't stream would be a no-go for me

Comment: Live Streaming Audio in HTML 5: http://wfmu.org/html5/player.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/video.html#audio

edit:

> What's up with all that downloading?
>
> Opera, Chrome and Safari will automatically download the whole video file even if it hasn't started to play yet. Firefox 3.6 only loads enough to render a frame and determine duration, unless the autobuffer attribute is present. Note that the spec changed from autobuffer to preload, which hasn't been implemented anywhere yet. Opera plans to change to the Firefox behavior of only loading enough to render a frame and determine duration by default, unless the preload attribute says otherwise.

source: http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio/

Comment: Per my tests, as of today(2017-03-05), Firefox, Edge can start playing live audio stream fairly quickly (with delay of 1 to 3 seconds), The delay for Opera is about 10 seconds.  Tests are done with "audio/wav"